# Flutter: Save list of PDF files to Firebase Storage

Tags: list, flutter, pdf, firebase-storage

I have a list of PDFs that need to upload to Firebase Storage and get the all URL from that list that already uploaded to Firebase Storage to open each PDF. How to do that?

If not a list of PDF, I already success upload it with get the URL with this method:

```
Future<String> _uploadSingleFile(ResumeModel resume) async {
    var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(resume.name);
    var uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(File(resume.pathOrUrl));
    var downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.onComplete);
    var url = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());
    return url;
  }
```

But how to make that method support to save a list of PDF that already display in the ListView Builder like below:

[image]

This is the method to show a list of PDF file:

```
return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: listResume.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          var resume = listResume[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, top: 0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    ImageAssets.resume,
                    width: 47,
                    height: 47,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        resume.name,
                        style: SourceSansProStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            color: _themeData.textTheme.bodyText2.color),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                        child: Text(
                          resume.pathOrUrl,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: SourceSansProStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
```

and this is the variable for `listResume.length` ==> `List<ResumeModel> listResume = <ResumeModel>[];`

And this is my model:

```
class ResumeModel {
  final String name;
  final String pathOrUrl;
  const ResumeModel({this.name, this.pathOrUrl});
}
```

My question is:

1. How to upload a list of PDF to Firebase Storage (the list of PDF are from the device, I used it using file_picker)
2. How to get all URL pdf from a list that already uploaded (it's mean if number 1 it's already success uploaded to Firebase Storage) like `final String url = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());`?

Because if you see my function in `_uploadToFirebaseStorage()` it returns a URL but not a list, So I asked it in number 2.

EDIT:

I already created new function like below:

```
Future<List<String>> _uploadAllFiles(List<ResumeModel> resumeList) async {
    List<String> urlList = [];
    resumeList.forEach((resume) async {
      urlList.add(await _uploadSingleFile(resume));
    });
    return urlList;
  }
```

And I call it when click `Save` button like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
   var listURL = await _uploadAllFiles(listResume);
   print('List URL: ${listURL}');
   Navigation.back(context);
}
```

And the result of `listURL` it's `[]` and when I checked to Firebase Storage, it only saves 1 PDF file, but actually I tried to save 2 PDF Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this list coming from (the ones you said that are already uploaded). Are they already uploaded on your Firebase Storage? Were they uploaded via your app?

When you upload a file, and you have the URL, you could also store the metadata on your Firestore. The document would essentially be your ResumeModel. Then every PDF in your storage will have a corresponding document in your Firestore, with its URL stored.

I am not entirely sure if I understood the question to begin with. Let me know if this helps!

EDIT:
(Proper answer after some clarification)

Ok so wait until you have your full PDF list. When you click the Save button then you can call a new function, something like

```
List<String> _saveAllFiles(List<Resume> resumeList) async {
  List<String> urlList = [];
  String toAdd;
for (Resume resume in resumeList) {
    toAdd = await _uploadToFirebaseStorage(resume);
    urlList.add(toAdd);
}
  return urlList;
}
```

You will need to change your _uploadToFirebaseStorage function to take in a single resume file

Comment: Sorry to make you confused about my question, I already update the question in the last paragraft

Comment: Thank you for more clarification. If you iterate the list of resumes, upload them one by one, and store each url in another list, does that solve your problem? Then you will have a list of the URLs after you upload each one.

Comment: `upload them one by one`: So it means can't upload as a list like I want?

Comment: Uploading a list would do it sequentially anyway.

Comment: You can use your _uploadToFirebaseStorage function on each resume file, return the URL and add it to your URL list !

Comment: If I do that, so I upload the resume to Firebase when I success upload a PDF from file_picker (it's mean when users click `Upload from Link` or `Upload from Device`). But I want to call `_uploadToFirebaseStorage()` when I click `Save` in AppBar if the user finished chooses the resume.

Comment: Ok so wait until you have your full PDF list. When you click the Save button then you can call a new function, something like 

List<String> _saveAllFiles(List<Resume> resumeList) async  {
     List<String> urlList = [];
     resumeList.forEach((resume) => urlList.add(await 
          _uploadToFirebaseStorage(resume));
    return urlList;
}

You will need to change your _uploadToFirebaseStorage function to take in a single resume file

Comment: I get error in `urlList.add(await _uploadToFirebaseStorage(resume));` it's because `.add` it's `void Function(String)` then `_uploadToFirebaseStorage()` it's `Future<String>`

Comment: I was wondering if it would be able to do it in the same line. I edited my answer again, try that,

Comment: `toAdd` is a `String` and `await _uploadToFirebaseStorage(resume);` it;s `Future<String>` so it can't.

Comment: you have to add the `async` keyword within the forEach. Ironically, I JUST had to do something similar in my code and its working!

Comment: actually, with that keyword it would have worked as the original one line one as well! my bad on that!

Comment: I tried it with have 2 `list PDF`. But it saves only one PDF to firebase storage and the return of `urlList` it's `[]`

Comment: the problem is its returning the urlList before it adds the url to the list. Unfortunately we cannot await a forEach. a temp solution is to include a `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));` after the forEach, and before returning the list. However I am looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: All right I found the solution. Apparently await does not work in a forEach. I altered the type of loop and it should work with this one. Let me know!

Comment: Thanks!!!, it's working. Now I just tried it to handle when the process still executes, shows the loading indicator.